# Exclude iCloud shared albums with fetching asset collections

Tags: ios, phassetcollection, phassetslibrary

I'm trying to fetch a list of all the albums in the user's photo library excluding any iCloud shared albums. Here is the code I am using so far:

```
PHFetchOptions *userAlbumsOptions = [PHFetchOptions new];
userAlbumsOptions.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"estimatedAssetCount > 0"];
userAlbumsOptions.includeAssetSourceTypes = PHAssetSourceTypeUserLibrary;

PHFetchResult *userAlbums = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeSmartAlbumUserLibrary options:userAlbumsOptions];

for (PHAssetCollection *album in userAlbums) {
    [self.albums addObject:album];
}
```

If I have understood correctly, the `userAlbumsOptions.includeAssetSourceTypes` property should filter out iCloud shared albums; however, they are still showing in the list. Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
PHFetchOptions *userAlbumsOptions = [PHFetchOptions new];
userAlbumsOptions.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"estimatedAssetCount > 0"];

PHFetchResult *userAlbums = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAny options:userAlbumsOptions];

for (PHAssetCollection *album in userAlbums) {
    if (album.assetCollectionSubtype != PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAlbumCloudShared) {
        [self.albums addObject:album];
    }
}
```

Basically, retrieve all asset collections, but only add them to the array of albums if the subtype is not `PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAlbumCloudShared`. This works, but I'm not happy with it. The `PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAlbumCloudShared` check should not be necessary.

Comment: can i get cloudOwner name who shared this album?